# HTML5 textfield history log using Local Storage

Tags: html, local-storage, storage, local

I have this code for a simple search function I use. I would like to add a history log using the HTML5 local storage function. 
I have tried to look at examples but I'm no good web coder so I don't really understand how to adapt the examples on my form.

All I wanna do is save the text in the textbox to a listbox so I easily can load the last searched text.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('txtNummer').focus();"> 
    <center>
<article>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <font size="22">S&ouml;k order</font>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <form action="test.php" method="post"> 
<input style="font-size: 44pt; text-align: center" size="9" type="text" name="txtNummer" id="txtNummer"/> 
<input type="submit" value="submit"">
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</article>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Thankful for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample for you. It saves the value of the `input` with id `test` when clicking on the button.

It checks whether the HTML Storage functionality is available and uses it to save.

For your convenience, I added an alert to show you the result.

```
function saveText()
{
    var e = document.getElementById('test');

    if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined')
    {
        var currentValue = localStorage.getItem('test');

        if (currentValue.length == 0)
        {
            currentValue = e.value;
        }
        else
        {
            currentValue = currentValue + '\n' + e.value;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('test', currentValue);

        alert('current value:\n\n' + localStorage.getItem('test'));
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Cannot access local storage.');
    }
}
```

Use that with this html:

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
<button onclick="javascript:saveText()">save</button>
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8W6X/2/).

Comment: @Charkel: Need more help? Was this answer helpful to you?

Comment: Nothing happens when I try the fiddle example. I've been trying to look at the code a few times now but I don't really know how to get it working. I tried to change the result from a textbox to other things but without success. I'm on a mac and tried the example on chrome and safari.

Comment: Does your browser support this feature?

Comment: Well yes it should. Latest version of chrome and safari, unless the code is windows specific there should be no problem.

Comment: If i try to run 
"alert('current value:\n\n' + localStorage.getItem('test'));" 
I get a message box with value "null" but if i click the button in the example nothing happens

Comment: Did you type anything in the textbox? It works here in chrome.

Comment: Yes I have tried different values. The example here works for me so the local storage works: http://html5demos.com/storage

Comment: Sure you didn't disable local storage for `jsfiddle.net`?

Comment: No I could not have as I dont know how and tried multiple browsers.

Comment: @Charkel: I updated the code to give an alert when it can't access the local storage.